# Restrict access to folder by username/password (nginx)

Tags: password, nginx

I have burnt my old server and now trying to reinstall my domain on the new server (Ubuntu 22.04). I remember the following code (nginx) used to work to restrict the admin folder - just an extra layer of security. However on the new server, after entering the user/pass, it displays a 404 error page. No files are missing.

```
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

So the question is, how to make this work on the new server? What I want is to restrict the admin folder with the username/password that are stored in the /etc/nginx/.htpasswd file.

If it matters, there are no error logs stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create an .htpasswd file:
You can create or update the .htpasswd file using the htpasswd command:

> sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd username

Replace username with the desired username. You will be prompted to enter and confirm the password for this user. If you're adding more users later, omit the -c flag to avoid overwriting the file.

Configure Nginx to use the .htpasswd file for authentication:
Edit your Nginx server configuration file, usually located in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or in a separate file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/. Add or modify the following section inside the server block:

```
location /admin {
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    # Additional configuration for the /admin location if needed
}
```

This configuration restricts access to the /admin URL and uses the .htpasswd file for authentication.

Test the Nginx configuration:
Before you reload Nginx, test the configuration to catch any syntax errors:

> sudo nginx -t

Now, when you access the /admin URL in your web browser, Nginx will prompt you for a username and password.

Remember to secure your .htpasswd file by limiting its permissions to the Nginx user and group to prevent unauthorized access:

> sudo chown www-data:www-data /etc/nginx/.htpasswd sudo chmod 600

> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd

Replace www-data with the appropriate Nginx user and group if it's different on your system.

Comment: so basically remove `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` if I read correctly. No, it didn't work, after entering the username/pass the result is the same (404). Besides, it seems to popup the access form when the directory only is accessed in the URL, and didn't work for site.com/admin/login.php